# Regular expression match in bash

Tags: regex, bash

In bash, how do I check if a string variable matches a given regular expression? It should be the fastest and most portable (OS X, Linux) method possible.

Basically I want:

```
if [ $MY_VAR matches '[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}' ]; then
    echo 'matched'
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be,

```
if [[ $MY_VAR =~ [A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12} ]]; then
    echo 'matched'
fi
```

In-order to do an exact string match, you need to add anchors.

```
$MY_VAR =~ ^[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}$
```